# How do I ingest multiple csv files from a server into multiple tables in an Azure Lakehouse?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl, pipeline, microsoft-fabric

I'm new to Azure. I need to ingest multiple csv files that are located on a server that can be accessed via a gateway. The csv-files are regularly updated.

How do I ingest the csv files into an Azure Lakehouse? Do I need one DataFlow per file and add them manually or can I read all the files into separate tables at once? What is best practise?

I have tried loading the folder in a DataFlow, but then I only get the metadata.

I have also tried using a pipeline and a ForEach-block, but then I have no way of accessing the local server files via the gateway.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the file name remain constant everytime and is there a 1:1 mapping between the file and the tables? If yes, then we can have a meta data driven pipelines to copy the data

Comment: @Nandan Yes. How do I read a csv file from a local server via a gateway with a pipeline? The closest alternative I can see in the list of pipeline sources is an FTP-server.

Comment: To copy the file in local server, you need to create and configure [self hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) in the local server. Then You can create FTP linked service  with integration runtime as self hosted and then copy the local csv files.